# How I could append a variable in a list after converted in variable

Tags: python, list, exec

I have this:

```
listVar=[]
listSel={'one':'x','two':'code'}
for row in listSel:
    exec("%s = '%s'" % (row,listSel[row]))
    listVar.append("%s" %row)
print(one,two)
print(listVar)
```

I convert the row in a variable with `exec()`, but i don't know how could i append the new  variables in the `listVar`; next to this i'm looking for inside the variable in a list with `listVar.append("%s" %row)`, my expected answer with print would be:

```
['x','code']
```

(Because I'm printing the variables `one` and `two`)

But when I print `listVar` Python answered me:

```
['one','two']
```

I don't want to use something like:

```
listVar.append(one)
```

Because I'll make a function and I'll not know the rows.

Edit: I need `listVar` to be `[one,two]` not `['one','two']`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Maybe, this is what you needed:

```
listSel={'one':'x','two':'code'}
one, two = listSel.values()
listVar= [one, two]
print(listVar)
```

Comment: Hello, i don't need the values like a string, i need the values like a variable.
I need `listVar` to be `[one,two]` not `['one','two']`.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, could you check this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156739/divide-a-dictionary-into-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156739/divide-a-dictionary-into-variables)

Comment: No, that don't work because i will not know the dictionary, the dictionary would the input, for example, if i run `Function({'one':'x','two':'code'})` my list would `[one,two]` but if i input `Function({'qw':'x','as':'code'})` my list would `[qw,as]`.

Comment: Why don't you use the dictionary directly? For example, you can access to keys using list1 = list(listSel.keys()), with this code, you have a list of the keys of your dictionary (names) and could access to dictionary values by iterating the list. Something like this [listSel[list1[0]], listSel[list1[1]]]