# Shortcut for unrolling a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say, I have a dictionary of data and their variable names, e.g.

```
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}
```

and I want to retrieve the values associated with a subset of keys. How can I do this without coding too much, i.e. extracting the variables one-by-one? Is there something like

```
a, c = dct['a','c']
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803419/create-variables-from-strings-in-python

Comment: I don't think it's a dup. He doesn't want to make a local variable for every key in the dict, he just wants to extract more than one key at a time.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. Extracting a subset of values without doing this one-by-one. I have edited by question accordingly

Comment: @abarnert It seems like he does want to make local variables. Otherwise this question seems to be in a liminal state of practicality

Comment: OK. What I have understood is that extracting local variables in a quick way is possible but not recommended. I guess because of the reasons given in the post mentioned in the first comment...

Comment: @Jan that's true, consider using another dictionary to store this subset in. If you have to just do it manually `a, c = d['a'], d['c']`. If you are beginning to use many variables (ie. `>=5`) then you should be using another dict)

Comment: Making local variables for a small, static set of names is perfectly reasonable, and practical. It's only a bad idea when you're trying to create a whole bunch of variables, or name them dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generator expression for this:

```
>>> d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> a, c = (d[key] for key in ['a', 'c'])
>>> a
1
>>> c
3
```

If you do this often enough that it's worth wrapping up in a function, that's trivial:

```
>>> def multiget(mapping, *keys):
...     return (d[key] for key in keys)
>>> a, c = multiget(d, 'a', 'c')
```

However, if you look carefully, you'll see that `multiget` is just [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) uncurried, and it's usually a lot simpler to just use that:

```
>>> a, c = operator.itemgetter('a', 'c')(d)
```

Comment: If I use this often enough I will still use `a, c = d['a'], d['c']`

Answer (score 1):

For educational purposes:

```
>>> d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> globals().update((k, d[k]) for k in ('a', 'c'))
>>> a
1
>>> c
3
```

However **never** actually use something like this

Comment: What? I loved your operator solution! Please get it back! (I was even about to up vote it)

Comment: @Haidro I realised it was useless (could just use a list comprehension) and OP's question *seems* to be different. You may use it in your answer incase OP wanted that

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it :p

```
>>> a, c = dct['a'], dct['c']
>>> a
1
>>> c
3
```

Please don't use `dict` as a variable name :). It's already a built-in type and function, so you've just overridden it :p.

Answer (score 1):

[`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is handy for this

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
from operator import itemgetter
a, c = itemgetter('a', 'c')(d)
print a, c
1 3
```

Comment: I didn't get to the `itemgetter` until the end of my answer, but I think it's usually the clearest answer, so… definite +1 here.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks, but ..your answer's a heck of a lot more educational, +1

Answer (score 1):

Like functional style ?

```
>>> d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

>>> a, c = map(d.get, ('a','c'))
>>> a, c
(1, 3)
```

Comment: Better not to use the `lambda`, `d.__getitem__` or `d.get` (when value may be missing) is much preferred eg. `map(d.__getitem__, ('a','c'))`

Comment: @jamylak Perfectly correct! I modified the answer accordingly. Thanks ;)