# Convert a string to a variable name

Tags: python-3.x

```
var_1 = "num_1"
```

how can I convert the string `num_1` into a variable name?

For example, when `num_1` is converted into a variable name it must be like `num_1 = "Some other data"`

Comment: Use `eval` (bad idea). Use `ast.literal_eval` (better idea). Manipulate `locals()` or `globals()` (tread carefully)

Comment: Could you please give me a sample code? I'm new to Python
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The other [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name) questions and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803419/create-variables-from-strings-in-python) have long discussions of why this is generally a bad idea.

Are you sure you can't just use a dictionary to store your values?

```
var_1 = "num_1"
myvars = {}  # create an empty dictionary
myvars[var_1] = 99
print(myvars["num_1"])
```